# How would you use componentDidUpdate to update something without having to refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So the F displays the # of movies favorited state and W represents the # of movies watched state.

[image]

I made a button that clears the # of favorites movies to 0 but for it to be updated I have to refresh the page. How would I use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle to update it without refreshing the page?

Could you just explain me the process?

Comment: Why do you need to refresh the page for the # of favorite movies to be updated? Can you include your code in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put your # of movies as a state, and I think componentDidUpdate isn't the best approach, you simply need a button `onClick` listener.

In your constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { movies: 0 }; // or movies: [] empty array
}
```

Then in your button component.

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    this.setState({ movies: 0 });
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the values in this.props then one thing you can do in componentDidUpdate is,

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props !== prevProps) {
    //update the state for movies favorited & movies watched.
  }
}
```

Another soln is, 
Initialize two states and then setState in **componentDidMount** in case of api call response.

And if those are coming from props, Use **componentWillReceiveProps** that will give you updated props in nextProps.

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
  this.setState({m_fav : nextProps.fav, m_watch: nextProps.watch})
}
```